# Why my C code on leetcode have different behavior between run code and submit?

Tags: c

Here is the problem's address.
https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array-ii/

And here is my C code:

```
int removeDuplicates(int* nums, int numsSize) {
    int* result;
    int result_pointer = 0;
    int allow_appearance = 2;
    int appeared_number;
    int i;
    if (0 == numsSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    result = (int*)malloc(numsSize * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        appeared_number = 1;
        result[result_pointer] = nums[i];
        result_pointer += 1;
        while (nums[i + 1] == nums[i]) {
            i += 1;
            if (appeared_number < allow_appearance) {
                result[result_pointer] = nums[i];
                result_pointer += 1;
                appeared_number += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < result_pointer; i++) {
        nums[i] = result[i];
    }
    free(result);
    return result_pointer;
}
```

Test data:
test case 1:[0, 0, 0, 0, 3]   (The 158th case)
test case 2:[0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4] (The 163rd case)

Correct output:
for test case 1:[0,0,3]
for test case 2:[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]

when i click Run Code, everything is ok, and the code run correctly on my macbook pro, using gcc as the compiler and gdb as debugger.

However, when I click Submit Solution, it output [0,0,3,3] for test case 1.
And then I try to comment out the code "free(result);", it output [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4] for test case 2. Test case 2 is behind the test case 1, which means that test case 1 was passed after commenting out the code "free(result);".

It seems that the code I comment out has no relation with the result, what's wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
while (nums[i + 1] == nums[i]) { ... }
```

Consider what happens with arrays like `[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`. It'll happily read past the end.

You need to stop the loop when you reach the end:

```
while (i+1 < numsSize && nums[i + 1] == nums[i]) { ... }
```